# How to present password rules

Tags: forms, password

How should feedback be given about password rules in registration forms?

a) When you focus on the password field

b) When you type the first letter of the password

c) When you stop typing, plus a small delay

d) When you tab away from the password field or click [Register], *if* the password does not meet the requirements.

Comment: e) don't have password rules and let the user enter whatever they like... ?

Comment: Are we there now? If the user wants "123" as his password, we let him?

Comment: Well we could be, but that's not exactly what I'm saying. I'm just suggesting that your a-d aren't your only options. From a pure UX point of view then shouldn't allowing your users to use whatever they want as a password something worth considering?

Comment: `123` in one's head is better than `S1lverman` in one's notebook.

Comment: you also might want to consider providing feedback as to what rule was violated, and not just grunt "not valid, see rules" which forces the user to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: related: [Is it safe to show users why their password is not allowed?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/40564/3272)

Comment: @forthrin Yes, if the user wants "123", let them. It's their account they leave basically open for everyone, not yours. It's just like your landlord cannot really force you to actually lock your door, though you usually do

Comment: I would let them use "123" but give them feedback as to why it's bad/good, eg "This password looks easy to guess" or "Great password very strong"

Comment: @bendataclear [exactly](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/43958/7228) :)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Only problem being that your tenants door means your insurance policy is void. So yes, password rules are definately needed, otherwise in the long run it will end in a very messy PR/Clear up operation when something does go wrong

Comment: @tim.baker There's just one catch: Typically the ridiculousness of a website's password rules is inversely proportional to the website's importance. And to top it off, those "high security password" sites then send your password in plaintext via e-Mail.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I agree, some websites are stupid in how they go about it. Though you can't allow users passwords of 3 charactors such as 123 - no rules mean they could just use a one digit password, or even the dreaded "password" itself!

Answer (score 17):

## When to display invalid password input?

In the case of password fields, research strongly suggests that **as-you-type** (with short delay) is the way to go. Luke Wroblewski has shared [great experiment results](http://alistapart.com/article/inline-validation-in-web-forms) answering your very question; Smashing Magazine also has a [good article](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/27/form-field-validation-errors-only-approach/) on this.

[image: A form showing inline validation]

## Where to display the password rules?

- **Always** - increases cognitive load. The password rules are only relevant to the user when they type their password. (You can derive at this by means of design over-dissection - if the form would turn a wizard, where would you put the rules?).
- **On Focus** - Optimal option.
- **On Blur** - This may be a tempting option since users *may* enter a valid password, so why bother them with rules? But if there is an expected behaviour from users you should inform them beforehand rather than telling them off afterwards. The cash point example below exemplifies this:

[image: A wireframes of two different cash points.]

Comment: The second blue one reminds me of [Out of Cream!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0Bt0lkpV_U)... or [Computer says no...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOdjCb4LwQY)

Answer (score 8):

First I have to say is try and avoid them as people tend to reuse passwords and unique password rules make it easier to forget. Having said that, I myself had to bow down to those rules, so I understand it's not possible always.

In terms of displaying, you want the user to remain in control, so you want her to stay informed before typing in a password. This would allow the user to decide on a password and them take action on it (focus on the field, and type).So I think it should be visible all the time and not on focus or later.

You could do a highlight on the rules on focus, to help ensure that the user has not missed them, or forgotten them.

Comment: Users are so educated on passwords these days that there's no point in enforcing rules?

Comment: I agree, if there are rules, be open about them. Visual clutter etc. are a different problem that can be solved in many ways. Hiding the fact that there are rules is not the way to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

While your question ask on *how* to display password rules, I would instead like to argue *why not to enforce* any password rules at all, and why they are bad ux. I'm strongly resisting the urge to inline [the obvious XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/936/) here, instead concentrating on points already made in the very related question on security.SE, [Is it safe to show users why their password is not allowed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/40564/3272), and I'd like quote from both [Tom Leek's accepted answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40569/3272) and [mine](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40596/3272):

> [Tom Leek] In any case, "password requirements" are counter-productive and *decrease* security, save for a "minimum length" which can be rationally justified. So just don't do that. Key to password security is **user education**, possibly helped with some tools (e.g. a random generator for strong passwords).

> [me] I recommend ***not* forcing users to choose an arbitrarily complex password** that they will simply end up **writing down on a post-it next to their monitor** (or having them reset their password as simplified "login"). Instead, let them know *that* their password is weak, tell them what a good yet memorable password is (e.g. use a pass- *phrase* instead) and allow them to proceed anyway after clicking a "Yeah, I understood my password is not very secure, let me proceed anyway" - it's their fault if the account gets hacked then and you should not be liable after this explicit warning. Assuming *you* did use a proper and established password hashing instead of homebrew-crap or, worse, plaintext.

So in summary, instead of displaying some arbitrary password "rules" anywhere, please simply provide a link "How to choose a good passphrase?" (phrase, not word!) and add a "password/phrase strength indicator" next to the field. Allow even something as moronic as "123" or "password" but make it clear that you don't take any responsibility for the user's not using something more secure.

And finally, take care you [store the password/phrase securely](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4781/3272) and *never* as plaintext! See also [here](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/257.html)

Comment: Excellent points! Inform, but not enforce. Now, where is everyone's favorite JavaScript passphrase strength calculator that I can borrow?

Comment: Glad to hear you agree :) StackOverflow to the help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/948172/321973, and http://webtecker.com/2008/03/26/collection-of-password-strength-scripts/. Here's a nice read (on a quick glance at least): https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/ linking to https://github.com/lowe/zxcvbn - that latter one looks quite informative: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209/zxcvbn/test/index.html

Comment: (though the latter is a bit _too_ verbose for my taste - I would instinctively distrust a website that shows my password in cleartext)

Comment: While zxcvbn seems brilliant: 680K for this? Is there a small one that does not use a framework and still does a great job?

Comment: That certainly depends on the complexity you want - a small checker will simply not be as sophisticated, but then again it's probably not your responsibility to give a _precise_ estimate, so a simple entropy-meter might suffice

Comment: btw note how zxcvbn's author [states](https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/) "`zxcvbn-async.js` is a measly 350 bytes. On window.load, after your page loads and renders, it’ll load `zxcvbn.js`, a fat 680k (320k gzipped), most of which is a dictionary. I haven’t found the script size to be an issue; since a password is usually not the first thing a user enters on a signup form, there’s plenty of time to load. Here’s a [comprehensive rundown](http://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/) of crossbrowser asynchronous script loading."

Comment: I'll look around for a leaner alternative. Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: Well of course an even better choice might be using OpenID instead of another password, to use your StackExchange/Facebook/google/... account to login

Answer (score 2):

I like the following pattern.

There are couple benefits. Firstly you show what the password is expected to contain "the rules" so the user has a clear expectation of how they need to pick/formulate the password.

The second benefit is that you prepare and reflect back to the user when they have achieved the "criteria". The instant feedback avoid the whole submit - error - retype cycle.

[image: Inline password validation]

If you use a confirm password input as well this cycle can be increased as the user (nor the system) knows which password was entered incorrectly so they have to type both again - Slightly off topic this paragraph though.

Answer (score 1):

The syntactical rules that govern passwords should be displayed always (or whenever it's possible to set the password), preferably right next to the password entry field(s).

Violations of the syntax should be indicated as soon as possible.  Sometimes this means when the offending character is typed, but also consider the initial state violations. If a numerical digit is required, the initial state of the password field (empty state) will be in violation of this and this should be indicated.  When the violation is addressed (they type in a number) this should be indicated (possible by graying out or crossing out the violation notice).

Rule of thumb: **the user should know whether or not the password is acceptable as soon as possible**.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fair to refer to the other answers for the question, but I would like to add the following:

If you have password rules then also present them on login as well as register.

This way any of the massive number of users who prepend a 1 or a ! to the end of their commonly used simple password will have a useful reminder.

Many users just repeatedly use a common dictionary password. If they've been pushed off this track by complex password rules then they might not remember your site has complex rules in the first place, reminding them will help them to think of what they might have entered, i.e. did they use the complex password they use repeatedly when they need to, or their common password with a special character prefix, etc.

So aside from presenting the password rules on register which is not a commonly used password related page the rules should also be displayed on the login page which will be used much more often.

Something along the lines of 'for security reasons we required you use a password with one special character' near the password field.

This suggestion is based on three pieces of provable evidence ...

1. that users choose poor passwords en masse.
2. that users re-use the same password for many things
3. that users often have poor memories for things like passwords, especially when a long time lapses between usages and with visual memory removed through password obfuscation.

... and then on the deduction that a user who chooses a dictionary password is not suddenly going to choose a random string of 15 keyboard characters just because a special char is required. Therefore there's a good chance you could jog their memory. It would be an interesting test, though I can find no such test online.

Comment: Not really "rules" if it's only a recommendation shown when you log in.

Comment: the question is clearly about _presenting_ password rules, not about what the _rules are or should be_, so I recommend they are presented on login for better usability

Comment: And, even though I say so myself, it's a very good suggestion, relevant to the question !

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it should be displayed on log in? Do you mean before you log in, or on the form? The user should already know their password when visiting a site, no?

Comment: If I go to log into a website and I don't know my password, a tool-tip telling me "your password must be 8 characters, and contain 2 special characters" won't make me remember what I chose.

Comment: perhaps not, but in the case where you use a common password, as many users do, then are confronted with a password box where special rules have been required, but you don't remember this from when you signed up, then it would be very useful to jog your memory - the point is with this sort of thing is that users don't know their passwords when they've been asked to make them different from what they usually use in some way

Comment: +1 for addressing a pet peeve of mine. @ColinSharpe mentions the case where my standard password is too simple and a site needs more. There's also the case where my standard includes symbols that are restricted by some sites. (Why oh why??) In those cases sometimes the site gives its rules in the error message. If not, then I try again and again before walking away.

Comment: +1 - I do use the same password in some rule-implied variations for minor webservices, and though I'd prefer dropping these silly rules in their entirety having them displayed on login would really be helpful and stop me from using the "forgot password" button as "login" replacement...